# flutter How to combine multiple Map<String, dynamic>; in one variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm dynamically fetching data with the following function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < userFilter.length; i++) {
...
      url = 'fetching data dynamically';
      response = await http.get(url);
      extractedData = await json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
...
combinedData = extractedData
```

In the end my var `combinedData` is receiving `extractedData`. As I'm iterating through the list and I'm fetching data multiple times, I need to add the content of `extractedData` every time. I don't know how to add vars from type `Map<String, dynamic>` in one var. Does anybody have an idea?

At the moment I'm overwriting `extractedData` every time. I need to find a way to combine the result every time I successfully iterated.

Comment: If you want to combine several `Map<K, V>` objects together into a single `Map<K, V>`, use [`Map.addAll`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/addAll.html).

Comment: everytime when im doing this, im receiving null errror

Comment: Don't call `addAll` on `null` and don't pass `null` to it.  Otherwise you'll have to provide more details about what error you're getting.

Comment: yes of course, check my code, I have user filters with about 5 filter settings. for every filter we are going threw the above loop. extractedData is the data I need, it has 5 different results (for every loop im getting different data as user has choosen a different filter). At the moment I only receive the last result of extracted data ( when the loop finished after 5 times) I need to combine all 5 extractedData results in one var. It must be from type Map<String,dynamic> and im not able to put all the 5 Map<String,dynamic> results together in one Map<String,dynamic>

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't use `addAll`, and it shows no `null` checks.

Answer (score 1):

Define `combinedData` as an empty list before getting data in the for loop. Inside the for loop, append the data you've obtained into `combinedData`. After the for loop, use `combinedData` anyway you want.

Code example:

```
// combinedData is a list that contains
// Maps with a String as key and anything (dynamic) as value
final combinedData = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];
for (var i = 0; i < userFilter.length; i++) {
  // ..
  // ..
  combinedData.add(extractedData);
}
```

Comment: hey there, thank you for the reply, that sounds good, could you provide me an example how to correctly convert that? I have to say im not good in working with maps. When I define combined data as empty list, do i say combinedData.add(extractedData) then? anyway I have the error type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'